# JavaScript error "insertDealAddNote" is not a function when it exists

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript function:

```
DealerSocket.TakeAction.insertDealAddNote = function () {
    var controller = "/DealAction/_AddNote?recordId=";
    var formId = "_DealAddNoteFormElement";

    DealerSocket.TakeAction.PostActionAndRefresh(formId, controller);
}
```

When I execute the code I receive an error that "DealerSocket.TakeAction.insertDealAddNote" is not a function.

I am calling this function in an onclick event as follows:

```
@Html.DSButton("Confirm", ExtensionMethods.ButtonPriority.Second,         
    responsiveStyling: false,         
    innerHtmlAttributes: new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "btnDealAddNoteConfirm" } }, 
    onClick: "DealerSocket.TakeAction.insertDealAddNote();")
```

What this should do is to call the view on a postback and populate it.

I know there is some customized functionality in this but I was hoping I could just get the gist of what the error is about.

I am really green with JavaScript so thank you for your patience.

Comment: Is the `DealerSocket` within scope of the click handler?

Comment: Pardon my silly question but how would I know that.  I believe that it is

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: i'm not clear on why there are quotes around the function call? i think the quotes is making it a string.

Comment: Not sure @T.J.Crowder it tagged it automagically I will get rid of it

Comment: @PhillipChan: Because that block isn't JavaScript code (I have no idea what it is), it's probably creating something like `<button onClick="DealerSocket.TakeAction.insertDealAddNote();"></button>`.  So, it seems like `DealerSocket` may not be in the global scope, as needed by the `onClick` handler.

Comment: @PhillipChan yes that is my MVC View code I just used that to show how the function is called in the onclick event just for some more information